# Echo images for multiple checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I am making a site with checkboxes for toppings on pizza.
I have the problem that whenever I select one topping it does show and image of that topping but if I select two toppings it still only shows one image.
How can I make it so that it echoes the images of multiple checkboxes?

This is my index.php for the checkboxes and values:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="process.php" method="POST">

<h4>Kies een Pizza:</h4><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Ananas">Ananas<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Ansjovis">Ansjovis<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Broccoli">Broccoli<br>



<h4>Kies een bodem:</h4><br><br>


Megadik: <input type="radio" name="bodem" value="Megadik"><br>

Dun: <input type="radio" name="bodem" value="Dun"><br>

Calzone: <input type="radio" name="bodem" value="Calzone"><br>

</p>

<p>

<input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="Koop Pizza">

</p>

</form>

<br/><br/>
<a href="http://phpopdracht.esy.es">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my process.php where it needs to happen:

```
<html>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['bodem']) && ($_POST['check'])){

$bodem = $_POST["bodem"];

echo("Je koos een pizza met:<br/> ");

}
else{

 echo("Geen pizza gekozen!");   

}



$selected_radio = $_POST['bodem'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}
if(!empty($_POST['check'])){}
foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}


//Toppings

if (($selected == 'Pepperoni')) {
echo "<IMG SRC=\"pepperoni.jpg\">";
}



if (($selected == 'Ananas')) {
echo "<IMG SRC=\"ananas.jpg\">";
}

if (($selected == 'Ansjovis')) {
echo "<IMG SRC=\"ansjovis.jpg\">";
}

if (($selected == 'Broccoli')) {
echo "<IMG SRC=\"broccoli.jpg\">";
}


//Bodems

if(($selected_radio == 'Megadik')) {
echo ("<p>En de bodem Megadik</p>");
echo "<IMG SRC=\"megadik.jpg\">";
}

if(($selected_radio == 'Dun')) {
echo ("<p>En de bodem Dun</p>");
echo "<IMG SRC=\"dun.jpg\">";
}

if(($selected_radio == 'Calzone')) {
echo ("<p>En de bodem Calzone</p>");
echo "<IMG SRC=\"calzone.png\">";
}

?>

<br/><br/>
<a href="http://phpopdracht.esy.es">Home</a>

</html>
```

Im sorry its in Dutch.

Comment: I would recommend you to translate all text, including variable names, to english. Sure, someone who don't know dutch can work it out with some effort, but why make life harder for the people who are trying to help you?

Comment: @Anders I for one appreciate that he left `Megadik` in there. **Megadik**.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$selected` is updated each iteration of the loop. Then when the loop is done it will keep the last value. It will not "remember" all the values it had while looping. So you need to echo the `img` tag in the loop (or, if you want them separately somewhere else, in another loop).

Also, you can shorten the code by not having an if clause per topping, but instead using the fact that the file names of the images correspond to the topping names.

Then you get something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
  echo $selected . "</br>";
  echo "<img src=\"" . $selected . ".jpg\">";
}
```

Or if you want the separately:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
  echo $selected . "</br>";
}

//Some other stuff...

foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected) {
  echo "<img src=\"" . $selected . ".jpg\">";
}
```

Please note that is is recommended to write HTML tags in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you change the value of `$selected` inside the loop, but then check it outside the loop after it finishes:

You could make life easier on yourself by just applying the image inside your loop:

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $selected){
   echo $selected."</br>";
   echo "<IMG SRC=\"{$selected}.jpg\">";
}
```

Here is a working sample: https://eval.in/437716

Answer (score 1):

What happens when this piece of code executes:

```
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $selected){
    echo $selected."</br>";
}
```

On each iteration you echo the value. But when `foreach` is over `$selected` value is the last value of `$_POST['check']`. So, only your last value is checked against you `if` statements.
So the answer is - move your `if` statements into a `foreach` loop.